# How python-uno can manipulate libreoffice-calc with pipe?

Tags: python, sockets, uno

Python uno can communicate with libreoffice-calc via socket,the common way is to launch libreOffice-calc from the shell:

```
soffice --calc --accept="socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager"
```

soffice can communicate python-uno with socket and port:2002.

```
sudo netstat -anp  |grep  soffice
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2002          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3115/soffice.bin    
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     45712    3115/soffice.bin     /tmp/OSL_PIPE_1000_SingleOfficeIPC_7fb3858dfd518f4aa054b3e7cf720
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     45702    3115/soffice.bin     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     45716    3115/soffice.bin
```

Then you can open a python shell ,`import uno` to manipulate `calc`.

Now i open an `calc` from menu:

[image]

When you start soffice from menu:

```
sudo netstat -anp  |grep  soffice
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     49386    3200/soffice.bin     /tmp/OSL_PIPE_1000_SingleOfficeIPC_7fb3858dfd518f4aa054b3e7cf720
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     49390    3200/soffice.bin     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     48919    3200/soffice.bin
```

soffice can not communicate python-uno with socket ,the port:2002 is not opened.

How can manipulate the `calc` with python-uno when `lilbreoffice-calc` started from menu?

Comment: Is the issue that you want to start LibreOffice Calc from the menu, with the same parameters as when you launched from the shell?

Comment: Without the same parameters,how to revjise it then?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a Python question but you need to modify the .desktop file for LibreOffice Calc and add the configuration parameters.
You could for example open a terminal window and type:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-calc.desktop
```

Then find the row Exec which probably looks like this: libreoffice --calc %U
Add your parameters:

```
libreoffice --calc --accept="socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager" %U
```

Be sure to keep the %U at the end of the command to keep it functioning as before.

Save, and now it should work!

Comment: Kindly thank to your attention,edit  calc.desktop only bypass the issue,instead of solving it directly.

Comment: If you want to interact with LibreOffice via UNO you must launch the application in this way. It does not listen to any resources by default for security reasons.